# Want to write mongodb query that all the numbers that are not between particular range

Tags: database, mongodb

Below query i have written to get range between 400 to 800

```
db.products.find({$and: [{price: {$gt: 400}}, {price: {$lt: 800}}]});
```

But how to get values that are not between range of 400 to 800

```
db.products.find({$and: [{price: {$lt: 400}}, {price: {$gt: 800}}]});
```

why above query not shown any result?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple $or will do the job:

(price cannot be <400 & >800 at the same time ,
but can be <400 or >800 at the same time)

```
db.collection.find({
  $or: [
    {
      "price": {
        $lt: 400
      }
    },
    {
      "price": {
        $gt: 800
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yPUJLX7a0w0)

Comment: Thank you @R2D2 it's working fine but why $and is not working

Comment: need to be $OR because  $NOT($AND) == $OR